# Почему не рисуется маршрут в google maps direction api?

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, google-maps-api

Я пытаюсь нарисовать маршрут между двумя координатами. Проект состоит из нескольких фрагментов, когда фрагмент с картой загружается, по координатам сразу должен отрисоваться маршрут.

```
fun setLatLng(origin: LatLng, destination: LatLng){
    Log.d(TAG, "setLatLng: получение From: $origin, To: $destination")
    this.origin = origin
    this.destination = destination

    val url: String = getDirectionsUrl(origin, destination)!!
    val downloadTask = DownloadTask()
    downloadTask.execute(url)
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun downloadUrl(strUrl: String): String?{
    var data = ""
    var iStream: InputStream? = null
    var urlConnection: HttpURLConnection? = null
    try {
        val url = URL(strUrl)
        urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        urlConnection.connect()
        iStream = urlConnection!!.inputStream
        val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(iStream))
        val sb = StringBuffer()
        var line: String? = ""
        while (br.readLine().also { line = it } != null){
            sb.append(line)
        }
        data = sb.toString()
        br.close()
    }catch (e: java.lang.Exception){
        Log.d(TAG, "downloadUrl: ${e.toString()}")
    }finally {
        iStream!!.close()
        urlConnection!!.disconnect()
    }
    return data
}

private fun getDirectionsUrl(origin: LatLng, dest: LatLng): String? {

    val str_origin =
        "origin=" + origin.latitude.toString() + "," + origin.longitude
    val str_dest =
        "destination=" + dest.latitude.toString() + "," + dest.longitude
    val key = "key=$apiKey"
    val parameters = "$str_origin&$str_dest&$key"
    val output = "json"
    return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/$output?$parameters"
}
inner class DownloadTask: AsyncTask<String?, Void?, String?>(){

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        val parserTask = ParserTask()
        parserTask.execute(result)
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): String? {
        var data = ""
        try{
            data = downloadUrl(url[0].toString()).toString()
        }catch (e: Exception){}
        return data
    }
}
inner class ParserTask: AsyncTask<String?, Int?, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>?>(){
    override fun doInBackground(vararg jsonData: String?): List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>? {
        val jObject: JSONObject
        var routes: List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>? = null
        try{
            jObject = JSONObject(jsonData[0])
            val parser = DataParser()
            routes = parser.parse(jObject)
        }catch (e: java.lang.Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return routes
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>?) {
        val points = ArrayList<LatLng?>()
        val lineOptions = PolylineOptions()
        for(i in result!!.indices){
            val path = result[i]
            for (j in path.indices){
                val point = path[j]
                val lat = point["lat"]!!.toDouble()
                val lng = point["lng"]!!.toDouble()
                val position = LatLng(lat, lng)
                points.add(position)
            }
            lineOptions.addAll(points)
            lineOptions.width(8f)
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED)
            lineOptions.geodesic(true)
        }
        if (points.size != 0) mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions)
        builder()
    }
}
```

Рисовать маршрут должна функция onPostExecute. Если в режиме дебага поставить на функию точку, то приложение не останавлиется, но, судя по тому, что срабатывает метод builder в конце функции, сама функия срабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

Написал дополнительные логи, обнаружилось, что при отправке url запроса приходил ответ

> this ip, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this api key. request received from ip address *.*.*.*, with empty referer

Помогла замена API ключа